# Delete first character of string if it is 0

Tags: javascript, string

I want to delete the first character of a string, if the first character is a 0.  The 0 can be there more than once.

Is there a simple function that checks the first character and deletes it if it is 0?

Right now, I'm trying it with the JS `slice()` function but it is very awkward.

Answer (score 1319, accepted):

You can remove the first character of a string using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
var s1 = "foobar";
var s2 = s1.substring(1);
alert(s2); // shows "oobar"
```

To remove all 0's at the start of the string:

```
var s = "0000test";
while(s.charAt(0) === '0')
{
 s = s.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: @Stephen: In this case, it wouldn't make a difference because `charAt` always returns a string, even if the index exceeds the index of the last character, so there's no type coercion performed, and the algorithm ends up being identical. But I do prefer `===` over `==` even when it doesn't make a difference. ;)

Comment: @user113716 Wouldn't that exactly be the reason to use === so that javascript doesn't have to check if the types are the same?

Comment: @Hejner: The performance difference is negligible on modern JS engines, so it's quite unnecessary. Depends on your preference.

Comment: @Hejner: If the types are the same, as they always would be in this case, then `===` and `==` perform precisely the same steps (according to the spec, at least), so there is no reason to expect one to perform better than the other.

Comment: @TimDown actually not true, because you would have extra conditional logic for type checking.

Comment: @MiguelCoder. According to the spec, the steps are the same (browser implementations may differ, of course). Read it if you don't believe me.

Comment: While useful, your response does NOT do what was asked. 
The question asked for ONLY the first character to be removed.. your solution removes all similar characters at the beginning of a string.

Comment: @ReallyNiceCode putting aside the fact that the question was asked over 8 years ago. It was stated "The 0 can be there more than once." and the asker accepted my solution.

Comment: Although still valid, you should update your reply, by replacing `substr` with `substring`. Check MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 249):

Very readable code is to use [`.substring()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) with a start set to index of the second character (1) (first character has index 0). Second parameter of the `.substring()` method is actually optional, so  you don't even need to call `.length()`...

## TL;DR : Remove first character from the string:

```
str = str.substring(1);
```

...yes it is that simple...

### Removing some particular character(s):

As @Shaded suggested, just loop this while first character of your string is the "unwanted" character...

```
var yourString = "0000test";
var unwantedCharacter = "0";
//there is really no need for === check, since we use String's charAt()
while( yourString.charAt(0) == unwantedCharacter ) yourString = yourString.substring(1);
//yourString now contains "test"
```

### `.slice()` vs `.substring()` vs <del>`.substr()`</del>

**EDIT:** <del>substr()</del> is not standardized and should not be used for new JS codes, you may be inclined to use it because of the naming similarity with other languages, e.g. PHP, but even in PHP you should probably use [`mb_substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to be safe in modern world :)

Quote from (and more on that in) [What is the difference between String.slice and String.substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring)

> He also points out that if the parameters to slice are negative, they
> reference the string from the end. Substring and substr doesn´t.

Answer (score 109):

Use [`.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) and [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kCpNQ/

```
var myString = "0String";

if( myString.charAt( 0 ) === '0' )
    myString = myString.slice( 1 );
```

If there could be several `0` characters at the beginning, you can change the `if()` to a `while()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kCpNQ/1/

```
var myString = "0000String";

while( myString.charAt( 0 ) === '0' )
    myString = myString.slice( 1 );
```

Comment: Works great. Plus, `.substr` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Comment: const pathnameStandardized = pathname.charAt(0) === '/' ? pathname.slice(1) : pathname

Answer (score 88):

The easiest way to strip all leading `0`s is:

```
var s = "00test";
s = s.replace(/^0+/, "");
```

If just stripping a single leading `0` character, as the question implies, you could use

```
s = s.replace(/^0/, "");
```

Answer (score 28):

You can do it with [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method:

```
let a = "My test string";

a = a.substring(1);

console.log(a); // y test string
```

Answer (score 23):

One simple solution is to use the Javascript `slice()` method, and **pass 1 as a parameter**

```js
let str = "khattak01"
let resStr = str.slice(1)
console.log(resStr)
```

Result : hattak01

Answer (score 22):

Did you try the `substring` function?

```
string = string.indexOf(0) == '0' ? string.substring(1) : string;
```

Here's a reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

And you can always do this for multiple 0s:

```
while(string.indexOf(0) == '0')
{
    string = string.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
const string = '0My string';
const result = string.substring(1);
console.log(result);
```

You can use the `substring()` javascript function.

Answer (score 9):

```
var s = "0test";
if(s.substr(0,1) == "0") {
    s = s.substr(1);
}
```

For all `0`s: http://jsfiddle.net/An4MY/

```
String.prototype.ltrim0 = function() {
 return this.replace(/^[0]+/,"");
}
var s = "0000test".ltrim0();
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work, if only one 0 is in the string. But i need it also if the String looks like var s = "00test0"; then only the first two 0 had to be replaced

Comment: Why not `charAt`? Why the brackets? Why a prototype extension? Yuck.

Answer (score 6):

```
//---- remove first and last char of str    
str = str.substring(1,((keyw.length)-1));

//---- remove only first char    
str = str.substring(1,(keyw.length));

//---- remove only last char    
str = str.substring(0,(keyw.length));
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
s.replace(/^0/,'')
```

```js
console.log("0string  =>", "0string".replace(/^0/,'') );
console.log("00string =>", "00string".replace(/^0/,'') );
console.log("string00 =>", "string00".replace(/^0/,'') );
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative answer

```
str.replace(/^0+/, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
String.prototype.trimStartWhile = function(predicate) {
    if (typeof predicate !== "function") {
     return this;
    }
    let len = this.length;
    if (len === 0) {
        return this;
    }
    let s = this, i = 0;
    while (i < len && predicate(s[i])) {
     i++;
    }
    return s.substr(i)
}

let str = "0000000000ABC",
    r = str.trimStartWhile(c => c === '0');
    
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that doesn't assume the input is a `string`, uses `substring`, and comes with a couple of unit tests:

```
var cutOutZero = function(value) {
    if (value.length && value.length > 0 && value[0] === '0') {
        return value.substring(1);
    }

    return value;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TRU66/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to get the first character after deleting it:

```js
// Example string
let string = 'Example';

// Getting the first character and updtated string
[character, string] = [string[0], string.substr(1)];

console.log(character);
// 'E'

console.log(string);
// 'xample'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Javascript implementation of trim() > that removes and leading or ending spaces from strings. Here is an altered implementation of the answer for this question.

```
var str = "0000one two three0000"; //TEST  
str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'0'); //ANSWER
```

Original implementation for this on JS

```
string.trim():
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
 String.prototype.trim = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
 }
}
```

Comment: we don't consider confusion an implementation problem, however, it is often attributed to a capacity deficiency of keeping up with the variables your environment presents to you. In this case, your neural connections are incapable of handling the necessary understanding of this altered adoption of a native js function implementation as an answer to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

```
var test = '0test';
test = test.replace(/0(.*)/, '$1');
```

Comment: This doesn’t perform as expected and is also really inefficient.