# Selenium IDE: how to verify the stored text without some symbol

Tags: selenium, text, store, symbols, verify

1. I store the text in the format `"№XXX"`

   storeText | css=span.ng-binding | order_number
2. I need to verify this text in the other location using:

   verifyText | //div[@id='myorders']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td | ${order_number}.
3. The problem is that in that location this text is displayed without the symbol `"№" - "XXX"` only.

How i can to verify the match of this text?

Answer (score 0):

If the text in one location has the leading character, but not in the other, then after you save the string, strip off the first character and compare to that.  You can use any number of methods to do that (see [Delete first character of a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564414/delete-first-character-of-a-string-in-javascript)).

Klendathu

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

- storeText | css=span.ng-binding | order_number
- storeEval | storedVars['order_number'].replace('№','') | order_number