# JavaScript trim with character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
var str=",test,test1,test2,teset4"
```

How can I remove the ',' in front of the string? So the output will be something like this:

```
'test,test1,test2,teset4'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first character of a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564414/delete-first-character-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: how was this string generated, maybe there is a bit of a deeper issue than this simple removing first character of a string question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
str.substr(1)
```

```js
var str=",test,test1,test2,teset4"
alert(str.substr(1))
```

Comment: `str.length` is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Use any of these **[`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)**, **[`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** or **[`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)**.

```js
var str = ",test,test1,test2,teset4"
console.log(str.slice(1));
console.log(str.substr(1));
console.log(str.substring(1));
```

Comment: .substr and .substring too

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr`:

```js
var str = ",test,test1,test2,teset4"
console.log(str.substr(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str=",test,test1,test2,teset4";
while(str.charAt(0) === ',')
    str = str.substr(1);
alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```