# How to remove all '#' symbols if they are at the start of word using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and need to remove all '#' symbols, but only in case when they are placed at the beginning of the word. For example having next string:

```
"#quick ##brown f#x"
```

Should be transformed into:

```
"quick brown f#x"
```

How it could be achieved using regular expressions in javascript? Thank you in advance for help

Comment: What is the beginning of a word here? Start of string/whitespace?

Comment: Did you try searching? I ask because this has been covered many times in many different ways. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564414/delete-first-character-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = "#quick ##brown f#x"

var e = /(^| )#+/g
a.replace(e, "$1")
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

use like this `(\s+)\#+|^#` .It will be prevent middle of the `#`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/YHteoR/2)

```js
console.log("#quick ##brown f#x".replace(/(\s+)\#+|^#/g,"$1"))
```

Comment: The output is incorrect. `'quickbrown f#x' !== 'quick brown f#x'`

Answer (score 0):

You could either split the string and replace every hash `#` sign that is at the beginning of the string.

```js
var str = "#quick ##brown f#x",
    res = str.split(' ').map(v => v.replace(/^#+/, '')).join(' ');
    
    console.log(res);
```