# Slice a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a querystring:

```
window.location.search
?myvar=kx
```

How would I slice off the '?' at the beginning? For example, in python I would do either:

```
str = str.lstrip('?')
```

or

```
str = str[1:]
```

How would I do either of those in javascript?

Comment: use `.split()` like `str.split('?')` what is your aim for doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first character of a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564414/delete-first-character-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use split if you want to get left or right after slicing:

```
var loc = "http://test.com?myVar=kx&myCar=BMW";
var res = loc.split("?");
var url = res[0]
var params = res[1]
```

If you want to get URL without queryString, you can try following:

```
var loc = window.location; // or new URL("http://test.com?myVar=kx&myCar=BMW");
var url = loc.origin;
```

If you want to get value of parameter in URL then you may use URLSearchParams which is quite simple and easy.

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let myVar = params.get('myvar');
```

You can also use it like this:

```
let params = new URL('http://test.com?myVar=kx&myCar=BMW').searchParams;
params.get('myVar'); // "kx"
params.get('myCar'); // "BMW"
```

If this is not what you want, you can try regex or other string operation which help you in finding what you want. You can check at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For the substring you can do the following:

```
str.substring(1)
```

For the `lstrip` you could use regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to specifically get everything after the beginning query, I would do something like the function below.

```
// function you can use:
function getQueryString(str) {
  return str.split('?')[1];
}
// use the function:
console.log(getQueryString("?myvar=kx")); // which returns 'myvar=kx'
```