# Remove First Character of (Original) String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564414/delete-first-character-of-a-string-in-javascript) but it's specific to deleting a character if it's a certain number (0, in that case).

I want to remove the first character from a string no matter what it is.

`splice()` and `shift()` won't work because they're specific to arrays:

```js
let string = "stake";
string.splice(0, 1);
console.log(string);
```

```js
let string = "stake";
string.shift();
console.log(string);
```

`slice()` gets the first character but it doesn't *remove* it from the original string.

```js
let string = "stake";
string.slice(0, 2);
console.log(string);
```

Is there any other method out there that will *remove* the first element from a string?

Comment: In JavaScript, strings are immutable so you cannot remove the first character. You can however make a new string without the first character, as [abney317's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468663/1115360) shows.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
let str = "stake";
str = str.substring(1);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: in addition, you can get a range of string: to remove last char: test.substr(1,str.length()-2)