# How to detect @ in input using ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to do like twitter posts where users writing his post and when writing @ to open user list and click to add in the input. so that way you can tag anyone in your post. For these things I tried to check first char yeah it's working but in input anywhere I type @ to run a function or open user list.

page.html

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea rows="3" (input)="searchPeople($event)" cols="20" formControlName="comment"
      placeholder="Tweet your reply" spellcheck="true" autoComplete="true" autocorrect="true" autofocus required>
    </ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

page.ts

```
searchPeople(ev: any) {
  // set val to the value of the searchbar
  let val = ev.target.value;
  let firstchar = val.charAt(0);

  if (firstchar === "@") {
    console.log("search people");
  }
  else if (firstchar === "#") {
    console.log("hash tag");
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first character of a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564414/delete-first-character-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Citizen this is not a duplicate question, and my question is totally different. I want to do like twitter posts where users writing his post and when writing @ to open user list and click to add in the input. so that way you can tag anyone in your post.

Answer (score 0):

### Mentions

I've done some digging into this and found the UI term for it is "mentions".

Searching that brings up quite a lot of options for example:

- [dmacfarlane/angular-mentions: Angular mentions for text fields.](https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions)

Which is a port for the now-defunct AngularJS directive, Ment.io.

### Setup:

You can set this up by doing the following:

Add the package as a dependency to your project using:

```
npm install angular-mentions
```

Add the CSS to your index.html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Add the module to your app.module imports:

```js
import { MentionModule } from 'angular-mentions';
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [ MentionModule ],
    ...
})
```

Add the `[mention]` directive to your input/ion-input element:

```html
<input type="text" [mention]="items">
<ion-input [mention]="items"></ion-input>
```

Where `items` is a string array of the items to suggest. For example:

```js
items: string[] = ["Noah", "Liam", "Mason", "Jacob", ...
```