# Turning a string from PascalCase to param-case: remove extra dash at the beginning

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to turn a string from `PascalCase` to `param-case`:

```
'HelloWorld'.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (str) => { return '-' + str.toLowerCase() })
"-hello-world"
```

As you can see, I'm almos there ... I just have to remove the `-` at the beginning of the string. How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove first character from a Javascript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923015/remove-first-character-from-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Code, for removing the first word, you just need to ignore the first character by using `substring(1)` off your rest of the output

```
var output = 'HelloWorld'.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (str) => { return '-' + str.toLowerCase() }).substring(1);
```

or alternatively you can convert from pascalcase to camelcase by doing this

```
var output = 'HelloWorld'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/g).map(function(value){ return value.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+ value.substring(1)}).join("-");
```

**DEMO Below**

```js
var output = 'HelloWorld'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/g).map(function(value){ return value.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+ value.substring(1)}).join("-");
document.body.innerHTML += output;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use follow code:

```js
var name = "HelloWorld";
var paramCaseName = name.replace(/([A-Z]+(.))/g, function(_, separator, letter, offset) {
  return (offset ? "-" + separator : separator).toLowerCase();
});
console.log(paramCaseName);
```

Based on **angular** source code.