# how do I create a page name from the location.pathname url?

Tags: javascript

I have the following url :

http://localhost/get/this/url/in/a-nice-format.html

```
var pagename= location.pathname.split('/').join(':');
```

gives me

```
:get:this:url:in:a-nice-format.html
```

How do I get rid of the first ":"?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove first character from a Javascript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923015/remove-first-character-from-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pagename = location.pathname.split('/').join(':').substr(1);`

Comment: Awesome :) Love one liner Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use substrings method. Simply do this....
var pageName2 = pageName.substring(1); I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment yet but waned to help anyway. And there's probably an answer somewhere else...

Anyway, try using slice() and passing in a 'begin' argument of 1 to remove the first ':'.

Like this: var pagename= location.pathname.split('/').join(':').slice(1);